# Image doesn't appear when placing it in a card view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-cardview

I am loading images from firebase and loading them into card tiles in a staggered recycler view. I want the width of the photos to be consistent and match parent, and the height to change depending on the height of the photo.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong but the images don't show. I can see a thin line where the photo should be, kind of seems like it is the photo but it had like a 1px height, just a horizontal line.

This is my xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image_card"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_dread"
            android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I also tried to wrap the imageView in another layout such as follows:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image_card"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_dread"
            android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I've tried both relative-layout or vertical linear-layout and tried both with the height being either wrap content or match parent, and neither work.[image: This is the recycler, the lines aare supposed to be the photos]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code and let me know you can see your image or not.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewBinary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/splashlogo" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If this not help then check below things are perfect in your project or not:

1) `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'` make sure you added dependency.

2) Try to change `drawable` and check your layout.

If still you are facing issue then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_dread"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/no_dread"
```

in your Imageview, it works to me

Answer (score 0):

use a container view like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout as the first child in the card view. Then you can place the content in that layout anyway you want.

Example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/ap"
```

Then continue with the above scenario

Update: as cardview is confusing so that is the scheme I mainly use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/balon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/card_title"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/card_content"
                android:textColor="#555" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/action_share"
                android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/action_explore"
                android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Tried but it didn't work. I've added what I've tried.

Comment: Use this as test.    android:layout_height="160dp"
 Instead of the above in img section

Comment: It works when I give it to the imageView but not if I give it to the linear-layout/relative-layout or cardView

Comment: I have updated answer hope it goes fine in your project

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Your answer uses a fixed size for the photos though, where I would like each photo to b a different height. It could be landscape or portrait, no height constraints.

Comment: The idea is not in fixed size or dynamic size you should set environment right so image properties displayed  as expected . Change image as you like fixed or not then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to set the `scaleType` to `fitCenter` and `adjustViewBounds` to `true`:

```xml
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_dread"
            android:id="@+id/staggered_feed_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Reference: https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-for-android-imageview-scaletype-and-adjustviewbounds-64a1e4a35503

Comment: This indeed solved the issue of not showing the photo at all, but now all photos are 1: ratio. I can't figure out how to make their height dynamic and change according to the photo's actual dimensions. Tried every scale type